# How to fill a circle contour at the edge of an image?

Tags: python, opencv

[image][image]

In the image above, I want to eventually be able to fill in the contours of the colored circles. Unfortunately, the yellow circle on the bottom is right at the edge of the image, so `cv2.findContours()` doesn't work:

```
_, green_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(green_seg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Does anyone know how I can somehow fill in the yellow circle contour even though it's at the edge of the image? Since it's at the edge of the image, the pixel value on the bottom edge of the image doesn't complete the circle, isn't valued at 255, if that makes sense.

I looked online and some people say it's possible to draw a big box around the image and then do the contours, but if I do that, then opencv only draws the big contour around the entire image and not the circle.

Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The image I show above is just one case I'm considering. I'm trying to think how I can make this general enough such that for any contour that is at the edge of the border, I can still fill in the contour with cv2.drawContour().

Comment: Draw the line manually. Find the points of the yellow contour that are on the edge of the contour, draw a line with `cv2.line()`?

Comment: @Ahmet Thanks for your response! But I need to be able to do this automatically with code since there's a lot of these cases.

Comment: Are you sure fill doesnt work? Can you send original image so I can try?

Comment: Do you mean floodFill? Thing with floodfill is I need to be able to manually see where the contour is located. There are other images where the contour might be at the top edge or right edge, etc. Is the image in the question the one you're asking for?

Comment: Well, if you are finding the contours, you also know where they are. Its not relevant the location left, right etc.

Comment: You can totally draw a box around the mask! You just need to draw a BLACK border, not a white border! If it's white, it will be part of the contour. If it's black, it won't be. Simple as :). Just use `copyMakeBorder()`

Comment: @alkasm but if i draw a black border, it wouldn't be considered part of the contour right? since the pixel value would be different.

Comment: @Ahmet also, I'm actually not sure how i can send the image to you. do you know how?

Comment: Save your masked image as a PNG (so it's purely black and white) and edit your post with it. Should be sufficient! Don't draw over your image, pad the image with the extra border (i.e. your image will be slightly larger). You'll need to then shift the locations of the contour results since your padded image will have 1 more pixel in x, y added to each contour point.

Comment: @alkasm but then even if I shift the locations of the contours, they still wouldn't create a full circle/contour since there's no pixel value matching them at the border right?

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. You say "full circle/contour" but circles and contours are different things. A contour in OpenCV is a list of points defining a polygon. What do you want here? I think you'll need to update with a full description of the exact input and output you want.

Comment: @cmed123 please review the answers you got, up vote the ones that were helpful and click on the checkbox near the answer that better solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have (more or less) convex polygons, you actually CAN use `cv2.findContours`. Having the contours, try to find the center of mass, e.g. using [`cv2.moments`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga556a180f43cab22649c23ada36a8a139), and then use this as the seed point in [`cv2.floodFill`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717).

Please see the following code snippet. I assume, you can identify your polygons by color. Also, instead of some advanced finding of the center of mass, I just used the center point of the bounding rectangle of each contour. Maybe, that's also sufficient for your use case!?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up test image
colors = [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]
input = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(input, (100, 100), 50, colors[0], 10)
cv2.circle(input, (150, 350), 75, colors[1], 10)
output = input.copy()

# Iterate all colors...
for i, c in enumerate(colors):

    # Mask color
    img = np.all(output == c, axis=2).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Find contours with respect to OpenCV version
    cnts = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

    # Get bounding rectangles; derive seed points for flood filling; flood fill
    rects = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    seeds = [(np.int32(r[0] + r[2] / 2), np.int32(r[1] + r[3] / 2)) for r in rects]
    [cv2.floodFill(output, mask=None, seedPoint=s, newVal=c) for s in seeds]

cv2.imshow('input', input)
cv2.imshow('output', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

That's the input:

[image: Input]

And, that's the output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.1.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! I'm really sorry I forgot to mention, but the images I have are not necessarily all just on the bottom side. They may be on the left, right, or top side. So, the way I'm seeing it, floodfill wouldn't work since I have to actually look at it to see where the contour is.

Comment: @cmed123 This answer is saying to use flood fill from the center of the contour, not from the border, so your comment doesn't matter. However, this comment does assume that the contour is convex. Otherwise, there's no guarantee the center of mass is actually inside the contour, so this still isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way, perhaps not so precise, is to compute the convex hull for each contour and draw the interior with a fill color:

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

# load input image from the cmd-line
img = cv2.imread('test_images/partial_contour.png')
if (img is None):
    print('!!! Failed imread')
    sys.exit(-1)

output_img = img.copy()

# isolate just the colored drawings
ret, thres_bgr = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thres_bgr[np.where((thres_bgr == [255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0] # replace white pixels for black

# convert from 3-channels (BGR) to a single channel (gray)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(thres_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# this loop processes all the contours found in the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contourIdx, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    # compute a convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    # fill the inside with red
    cv2.fillPoly(output_img, pts=[hull], color=(0, 0, 255))

cv2.imshow('output_img', output_img)
cv2.imwrite('fill_partial_cnt_output.png', output_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```